# FileSaver.JS not working Android stock browser (NOT chrome)

Tags: javascript, android, filesaver.js

we send files to the client using the FileSaver.JS library (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

demo: https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

but on Android devices this demo does not work in the stock browser (NOT chrome/firefox/...)

Anybody any ideas for a work around ?

Regards

Comment: [It looks like a reported bug, and unfixed.](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/124)

Comment: yes i also found that, but that is why i am asking for some workaround :-)